# Java / java stored procedure avoid to load certificate from file system each time

Tags: java, ssl, stored-procedures, digital-certificate

I have done a java stored procedure on oracle database which uses p12 certificate to sign some data + SHA256withRSA. The certificate is located on database file system.
Each time I call the procedure the code will load a certificate from file system.

What I want is to know what other possibility exists to avoid loading certificate from disk each time the function is called? (maybe to store the file into array of byte?)

here is my example:

```
        KeyStore p12 = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
        p12.load(new FileInputStream("c:/cert/testfurs.p12"), "password".toCharArray());
```

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store it in a `static` field.

Static fields last for the duration of the database session, aka connection.

See this link for more detail: [Using Java in Oracle Database - Automated Storage Management With Garbage Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/chone.htm#BABFHGBJ)